# macOS - "No space left on device" with 250GB available after Catalina upgrade

Tags: macos, macos-catalina

My iMac is behaving strangely after upgrading to Catalina (10.15.4), even though my system says I have over 290GB available:

I'm getting error and warning messages regarding disc space, `No space left on device` when trying to build a golang binary, Chrome says `Failed - Disc Full` when trying to download anything, etc.

- I did find this [reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/bwrqxc/macos_catalina_file_system_changes_low_disk_space/) explaining that Catalina mounts a new volume, which probably has something to do with it.

  ```
  diskutil list

    /dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *24.0 GB    disk0
       1:                        EFI EFI                     314.6 MB   disk0s1
       2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         23.7 GB    disk0s2

    /dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk1
       1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk1s1
       2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk2         499.9 GB   disk1s2

    /dev/disk2 (synthesized):
       #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
       0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +523.6 GB   disk2
                                     Physical Stores disk0s2, disk1s2
       1:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD - Data     218.0 GB   disk2s1
       2:                APFS Volume Preboot                 83.4 MB    disk2s2
       3:                APFS Volume Recovery                528.1 MB   disk2s3
       4:                APFS Volume VM                      2.1 GB     disk2s4
       5:                APFS Volume Macintosh HD            11.0 GB    disk2s5
  ```

Has this happened to anyone else, and how do I solve it?

---

- Disc Utility Screenshots:
  [image: Storage]
  [image: Macintosh HD]
  [image: Macintosh HD - Data]

Comment: Have you tried to restart in Recovery Mode, then in normal mode?

Comment: @Didier Just tried, not much difference. The Disk Utility in Recovery mode did show "Disk Image" with just 10GB of storage in total, I wonder if that is the disc used for all Downloads or other operations.

Comment: In disk utility can you hit Cmd/2 to show all devices & provide a picture of the drive overview. Could you also from terminal try `diskutil cs list` & `diskutil list` - one will probably have no results, could you copy paste the other in your question [if you paste then select what you pasted & hit Ctrl/K [not cmd] then it will format legibly using markdown]

Comment: @Tetsujin Thanks for your reply, updated my question with the output from diskutil list.

Comment: OK, nothing at all wrong with that from what I can see. Next best guess, the golang thing [which I know nothing about, I'm afraid] is trying to build to the system drive, which is read-only & the lack of write perms is being mis-interpreted somewhere. All I can suggest is to check paths for it.

Comment: May the error message is misleading and should not indicate that the disc is full but that Chrome/go has no permission to write data where it is trying to save the download? Make sure the Privacy Disc and Folder protection does not prevent writing of the data.